# Unable to trap SIGQUIT signal in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, signals

Script:

```
echo $$
trap "echo \"hai\"" 3
while [ 1 ]
do
      ls >/dev/null
done
```

My requirement is to trap the SIGQUIT signal. So I execute the above script and press (CTRL + D). But it doesn't trap the signal and
it didn't print "hai". But it is properly worked if the signal is sent via 'kill -3 '. So, why CTRL+D is not worked?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that SIGQUIT is Ctrl \
Ctrl D being EOF

Comment: But this page `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm` have somemore different. Here they specify CTRL+D produce SIGQUIT signal.

Comment: Then they are confused.  You can check for yourself with `stty -a`.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news but did you try using Ctrl \ with `your` code? Your code works! :)